# How to pass extra variable in WP admin edit.php

Tags: wordpress

When editors go to edit.php

```
http://www.website.com/wp-admin/edit.php
```

I would like to automatically pass extra variables as

```
http://www.website.com/wp-admin/edit.php?orderby=123&order=desc
```

There is a solution with `wp_redirect` but it will create infinite loop.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `admin_menu` action,
The following code should work :

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', function(){
    global $menu, $submenu;

    foreach( $submenu['edit.php'] as $k => $v ){
        if( $v['2'] == 'edit.php' ) {
            $submenu['edit.php'][$k]['2'] = 'edit.php?orderby=123&order=desc';
            break;
        }
    }
}, 99 );
```